# File size limit for macros-vba in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a size limit where it may cause macros to not work some times? I'm at 450KB to 460KB after data entries. The issue is sometimes the time and date stamp doesn't work. I have the same form on 7 different computers and it happens randomly. Not sure if its a user error or code error but thought I ask the question on size limit.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim CC As Range
Dim CB As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Not Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 For Each CC In Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target)
    If CC.Value <> "" Then
        CC.Offset(, -2).Value = Date & " "
        CC.Offset(, -2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End If
 Next CC
 End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Not Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 For Each CC In Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target)
    If CC.Value <> "" Then
        CC.Offset(, -1).Value = Time & " "
        CC.Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    End If
 Next CC
 End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Not Intersect(Range("x16:x101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 For Each CC In Intersect(Range("x16:x101"), Target)
    If CC.Value <> "" Then
        CC.Offset(, 1).Value = Date & " " & Time
        CC.Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm"
    End If
 Next CC
 End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Not Intersect(Range("AC16:AC101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 For Each CB In Intersect(Range("AC16:AC101"), Target)
    If CB.Value <> "" Then
        CB.Offset(, -1).Value = Date & " "
        CB.Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End If
 Next CB
 End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Not Intersect(Range("Ah16:Ah101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
  For Each CB In Intersect(Range("Ah16:Ah101"), Target)
    If CB.Value <> "" Then
        CB.Offset(, -1).Value = Date & " " & Time
        CB.Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"
    End If
  Next CB
  End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Not Intersect(Range("Am16:Am101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 For Each CB In Intersect(Range("Am16:Am101"), Target)
    If CB.Value <> "" Then
        CB.Offset(, -1).Value = Date & " " & Time
        CB.Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"
    End If
 Next CB
 End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a [64kB compiled code limit](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010449_Maximum_Length_Limit_for_a_Macro.html) but this would not be affacted by data in your worksheet. Perhaps you're cluttering the RAM?

Comment: There is also a row limit (e.g: `max rows per sheet: 1,048,576 for Excel 2016`) which is dependent on which version of excel you are using

Comment: What happens precisely? 450 K is not much for an Excel file at all.

Comment: This question is a [X/Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked X but your actual problem is Y. Please [edit] your question and describe your actual problem. If the issue occurs only sometimes there is a high probability that you either run out of memory or use `.Activate` or `.Select`. • Please also note that *"not work some times"* is a useless error description.

Comment: Added Y to my X/Y question

Comment: You still didn't explain what your issue is. *"doesn't work"* is not an error description, because it is completely meaningless. There is no information in it that helps us to help you.